# RAML 1.0 does not obey !include in examples in responses.body

Tags: mule-studio, raml

I'm using the Mulesoft API designer tool to document my API

I've read the RAML 1.0 spec and, from what I understand, both of the following constructs should be legal, the only difference being in the way I access the json that appears in the `401` examples section.

```
/password:
  post:
    description: Verifies the supplied user name and password, returning the associated Customer Id
    body:
      type: tokens.password-verification-request
      example: !include examples/password-verification-request.json
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: tokens.password-verification-response-success
            example: !include examples/password-verification-response-200.json
      401:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: tokens.error-response
            examples:
              invalidcredentials:
                value: |
                  {
                    "failure" : {
                      "errors" : [ {
                        "code" : "ID10050",
                        "desc" : "Invalid User Credentials supplied"
                      } ],
                      "trackingId" : "e6d370da-3978-4dde-9e50-d485023cd47a"
                    }
                  }
              accountlocked:
.......
```

and

```
/password:
  post:
    description: Verifies the supplied user name and password, returning the associated Customer Id
    body:
      type: tokens.password-verification-request
      example: !include examples/password-verification-request.json
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: tokens.password-verification-response-success
            example: !include examples/password-verification-response-200.json
      401:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: tokens.error-response
            examples:
              invalidcredentials:
                value: !include examples/error.json
              accountlocked:
.......
```

The second of these two examples is flagged as an error in the designer, saying that it can't find "failure". I presume it is doing this as it tries to parse the contents of the error.json file

I am confident that the error.json file exists and is in the right place. I am also happy that it contains the correct json ( I copied the json from this file in to the `examples` property in example 1 above ).

Am I doing something wrong in the `!include`? Have I misunderstood the spec and does the spec not allow this? Is the API designer tool getting itself confused?

Answer (score 0):

The example !include can not be inner a JSON example you must specify like in the 200 example with the full example:

```
401:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: tokens.error-response
      examples: 
         - !include examples/error_01.json
         - !include examples/error_02.json
```

Comment: But how do I give more than one example for the 401 response?

Comment: I´ve edit the response to show how to use multiple examples!

Comment: If I try that syntax it tells me "examples should be a map".

Answer (score 0):

The actual syntax transpired to be:

```
  401:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: t.error-response
        examples:
          invalidcredentials: !include examples/errors/error-response-1.json
          accountlocked: !include examples/errors/error-response-2.json
          accountinactive: !include examples/errors/error-response-3.json
```